# better algorithm for counting points in grids

Tags: c++, algorithm

Suppose I have a point P in [0,1]*[0,1], and [0,1] is divided into m(say 200) grids. I use `A[m][m]` to indicate whether [a small square centred at P with length 2h] covers each grid or not. So for a point P, `A[i][j]` is either (increase by) 1 or 0.

Suppose I have n such points(P1,...,Pn), I want to calculate A(for each point Pi, I redo the above procedure, adding 1 or not). How can I do this efficiently(with C++) rather than writing 3 layers of for loops to check for each grid and each point(So O(nm^2))?

I tried the naive 3 for loops with C++. It takes longer time than using some of the vectorized operations(like `vector<= number` for comparing n numbers together, `A[bool vector, bool vector]` for subsetting) in R.

Since C++ is generally faster than R, is there any smart way to implement this process?

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]

double myfun(NumericVector u, NumericVector v)
{
    double n = u.size();
    double A[200][200] = {0};
    double pos[200];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        pos[i] = (double)i / 201;
    }

    for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 200; j++)
            {
                if ( (fabs(u[k] - pos[i]) <= h) && (fabs(v[k] - pos[j]) <=h ) )
                {
                    A[i][j]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    double s = 0, avg = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <200; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 200; j++)
        {
            s += A[i][j];
        }
    }
    avg = s / (200 * 200);
    return (avg);
}
```

Comment: What if you add some of the code you have explained in your question ? That would show that you've done something.

Comment: code is added(return the average of A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two inner loops only determine index of the point in your grid. But you can compute the index directly:

```
int i = (int)(u[k]*200);
int j = (int)(v[k]*200);
```

You probably also need to check that `i` and `j` don't reach the index 200. This only happens though, when `u[k] == 1.0` or `v[k] == 1.0`.

```
double n = u.size();
double A[200][200] = {0};

for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
{
    int i = (int)(u[k]*200);
    int j = (int)(v[k]*200);
    if (i == 200)
        i = 199;
    if (j == 200)
        j = 199;

    A[i][j]++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! One thing is, it is the square(centred at P with length 2h, not only P itself) covers the grid. By using your idea, can I do something like `int i_lower=(int)((u[k]-h)*200)` and `int i_upper=(int)((u[k]+h)*200)` to make two inside loops(smaller than my first version) between `i_lower` and `i_upper`, `j_lower` and `j_upper`?

Comment: @breezeintopl Yes, that should work. Every gridpoint in the interval `[i_lower+1, i_upper-1] x [j_lower+1, j_upper-1]` is completely covered by such a `2h x 2h` square.